# stack rows as columns based on another rank column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe as such:

```
                           offer_id   hurdle  hurdle_lvl  reward_value
0  5c0c1545a944456aa28dcf578e0cbdd2  35000.0           1         500.0
1  5c0c1545a944456aa28dcf578e0cbdd2  40000.0           2        1500.0
2  5c0c1545a944456aa28dcf578e0cbdd2  45000.0           3        3000.0
3  f21306541ae046edbdf0a79daea3a005    500.0           1          25.0
4  f21306541ae046edbdf0a79daea3a005    750.0           2         100.0
5  f21306541ae046edbdf0a79daea3a005  25000.0           2        1500.0
```

I need to reformat it such that

```
                       offer_id      hurdle_1  hurdle_2  hurdle_3  reward_1  reward_2 reward_3
0  5c0c1545a944456aa28dcf578e0cbdd2  35000.0   40000.0   45000.0    500.0    1500.0 3000.0
1  f21306541ae046edbdf0a79daea3a005  500.0     750.0     25000.0    25.0      100.0  1500.0
```

So stack the hurdle and reward rows as columns based on the hurdle_lvl column. Any help is greatly appreciated

So I used pivot table:

```
y.pivot_table(index=y.groupby('hurdle_lvl').cumcount(), columns='hurdle_lvl', values=['hurdle','reward_value'])
```

But this gives me a dataframe like the following:

```
hurdle                   reward_value                
hurdle_lvl        1        2        3            1       2       3
0           35000.0  40000.0  45000.0        500.0  1500.0  3000.0
1             500.0    750.0  30000.0         25.0   100.0  1500.0
```

The problem is that I lose the offer_id mapping. Any way to combine that to the pivoted table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_table` and sum common values.

```
out = df.astype({'hurdle_lvl': str}) \
        .pivot_table(['hurdle', 'reward_value'], 'offer_id', 'hurdle_lvl',
                     aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
out.columns = out.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                                  hurdle_1  hurdle_2  hurdle_3  reward_value_1  reward_value_2  reward_value_3
offer_id                                                                                                      
5c0c1545a944456aa28dcf578e0cbdd2     35000     40000     45000             500            1500            3000
f21306541ae046edbdf0a79daea3a005       500     25750         0              25            1600               0
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape - I am getting this. I know its because the offer_id isnt unique. can this be modified to have a unique constraint on multiple columns by any chance? So an (offer_id, start_date) pair is unique. We can assume start_date is also a column

Comment: OK. I'll fix that with pivot_table. Do you want to sum common values?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It’s much appreciated. I should formulate my question better but I just have a deadline 

Comment: @Fizi. I updated my answer with your input dataframe.

Comment: No. I just want columns based on hurdle_lvl. So there are 3 levels for each offer_id, start_dt pair. I am just trying to pivot it so that the levels become the columns. So three rows of offer, start_dt becomes a single row

Comment: If you have this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` it's because you have some common values (same index, same column) so you have to decide what do you want with this values (sum, mean, max, min, ...)

Comment: What is `start_dt`?

Comment: Hmm ok. I will take a look at my dataframe again. But I have unique offer_id, Start_dt. Each of them have 3 rows for each level and then I want to compress them into a single row. But will try your solution in a bit and update. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: start_dt will be another column. I figured it out. I just had to put all the other columns that define uniqueness as the index argument of the pivot function and then do a reset_index. Thanks again for your help